# Compare two wave files

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, digital

I have two .wav audio(stereo) files to be compared. The files may vary in frequency or amplitude or phase shift. How to compute the difference between the wave files in Scilab?  The expected output is that if frequency and amplitude differ between the audio files, the output must return that they are dissimilar.   Phase changes need not be compared.

Comment: Question seems very broad. what is the parameter you want to compare - frequencies, amplitudes, phase, etc. ?

Comment: The expected output is that if frequency and amplitude differ between the audio files, the output must return that they are dissimilar.

Comment: Even if phase changes are found between the audio files, it should not be considered. i.e) the output must return that they are similar

Comment: Spectrogram could be used for this application.

Comment: Please edit your question to add this new information.

Comment: But how will you use STFT for two wave files?

Answer (score 1):

Short Time Fourier Transform can be used for comparing the frequency and amplitude differences between two audio files. it can be implemented using basic windowing of audio followed by DFT operation over the windowed audio.

Comment: Could you please give me a sample code for the concept mentioned

Comment: you can find implementations on web following might help - https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Short_Time_Fourier_Transform.html                                                                                 
http://iitg.vlab.co.in/?sub=59&brch=164&sim=908&cnt=2                      and if this answer is fine you can accept it .

Answer (score 0):

Signal similarities can be found using the DTW algorithm. Then, you can follow the alignment path and check for phase changes in a localized/window perspective.